# Sails.js app failed to connect to MySql database in AWS RDS database, works with localhost(MySql)

Tags: amazon-web-services, sails.js, amazon-rds

I am new to sails. I have created an app with Sails. I have deployed the app to AWS. App works with localDiskDb. When I try connecting to RDS, I get the following error. I have set up connection URL in `sails.config.datastores.js`. When I see my error message, my feeling is that Sails still trying to connect to localhost. But I did not find any other place to replace that settings. I hope it's enough to change only connection URL. I am running Sails app with `developmenet` environment locally.

```
adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
url: 'mysql://USERNAME:PASSWORD@.................amazonaws.com:3306/DATABASE_NAME'
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgsPl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue. I had used a '#' in my password. It ruined this all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the 3306 port in your EC2 instance.

Do this in Security Groups by editing the Inbound Rules and adding a new TCP rule for the 3306 port AND specify your IP (where the app connects from) in order to not allow everyone access this service.

Comment: I hope I already did this. I can connect RDS via MySQL Workbench